# How to show toast message using JobScheduler

Tags: java, android, service, android-jobscheduler

I have been learning jobscheduler in andorid. I have trying to show a toast message in the onstartjob() after every 1minute. But its not showing up. Any help will be grateful.

**jobschedul_service .class:**

```
package com.prajwal.jobscheduler;

import android.app.Service;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class jobschedul_service extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After 15 minutes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
package com.prajwal.jobscheduler;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int LOAD_ARTWORK_JOB_ID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JobScheduler jobScheduler =
                (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder
                (LOAD_ARTWORK_JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, jobschedul_service.class))
                .setPeriodic(900000)
                .build());
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
  <service
        android:name=".jobschedul_service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"></service>
```

Comment: I guess you stuck in between and yet the implementation is remaining. Check out the link: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/05/example-of-jobscheduler-and-jobservice.html for complete guidance.

Comment: didnt worked still.

Comment: not working for repeating interval or else?

Comment: I cant see the toast msg itself. Also I added breakpoint on the values inside onstartjob(), but the breakpoint iself doesnt gets executed/catched. It is seen that it never calls the service class.

Comment: Is it because I m running the code in oncreate() of MainAct ??

Answer (score 0):

**Got the answer!**

The reason was the **setperiodic(long interval)**.

As per the ss below:
[image]

This function was added in API 21 i.e Lolipop version. Whereas I was running the app on version > Lolipop.

Whereas this new function in the image below:
[image]

was added in API 24 i.e. Nougat

Hence, if you are targetting your app below Nougat i.e < Nougat but >= Lolipop then use setPeriodic(long interval) method whereas if u r targetting >= Nougat then use setPeriodic(long interval, long flexinterval).

**Solution**

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            builder.setPeriodic(900000,6000);
        }
        else 
        {
            builder.setPeriodic(900000);
        }
```